# How can I add an additional site to my VPS server?

Tags: apache2, dns, vps, zone

I have a VPS hosting service. First of all, I installed bind9 and everything that my main website works just fine. Now, I bought another domain and set its nameserver address&ip to my website ones.

I added a configuration file of that site like '/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com' and I did 'a2ensite www.example.com' to enable the website to apache2. After one, when I reloaded my server, I see '000default' and 'www.example.com' in my '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/' directory.

I have thought I am done with settings, but I still cannot connect to the domain example.com. I think I have read it somewhere that I have to set up 'zone' thing which I did when I was setting dns.
For example,

```
zone "example.com"  IN {
        type master;
        file "example.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

Is this correct? If so, what are the things that I need to do afteron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a very descriptive answer [here](http://microreviews.org/basic-steps-for-setting-up-multiple-websites-and-subdomains-on-a-host/) It includes everything from hosting multiple domains to even getting sub domains up on the same VPS.